# Загрузка ссылки внутри WebView по нажатию кнопки - Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

У меня есть WebView, саму ссылку загружаю через `initialUrl: 'https://google.com/',`. Так же поверх WebView есть кнопка и при нажатии (через `onPressed () {}`) она должна загружать начальную ссылку, которую WebView загружает при запуске программы. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите сделать кнопку `Домой`. Чтобы по нажатию переходила обратно на главную страницу.

```
Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();

String _initialUrl = 'https://flutter.dev';

Future<void> _goHome() async {
  WebViewController webViewController = await _controller.future;
  await webViewController.loadUrl(_initialUrl);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
      children: [
        WebView(
          initialUrl: _initialUrl,
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
            _controller.complete(webViewController);
          },
        ),
        Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () => _goHome(),
            child: Text("Go home")
          ),
        )
      ],
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: Всё верно, да, спасибо большое :)